# get list in python

Tags: python, list, edges

```
#ideal nodes list should be
['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N']
```

So I tried to write a definition to read the nodes and edges.Here is my code,but it seems does not work.

```
""" read nodes"""
def rd_nodes(a):
    nline =[line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',') for line in a]
    for i in nline:
        return i
```

Comment: I think you should be using `yield` and not `return` in your `rd_nodes`

Comment: Show us the data structure for `graph`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it seems like yield and return have the same function.but when I tried,it still won't get the right result.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the graph should be the list with tuple.Check above dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) can help you here.

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""

nodes = set()
edges = set()

for line in s.split():
    clusters = line.split(':')[1].split(';')
    for cluster in clusters:
        _nodes = cluster.split(',')
        nodes.update(_nodes)
        edges.update(combinations(_nodes, 2))
```

You may use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) structure for `nodes` and `edges` to maintain order if you want. Just use nodes and edges as dict keys and then at the end of the script get list of the keys.

Comment: does it have any way like we don't import any packages,and to write a definition with for loop to get nodes and edges?

Comment: Sure, just check the link to combinations function doc I provided in the post, there's a pure Python version of it.

Answer (score 0):

As @skovorodkin has the correct answer, but if you want pure Python version (Though I wonder why) you could use this code

```
s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""
def combinations(nodes):
    if len(nodes) < 2:
        return (tuple(nodes))
    else:
        i = 1
        ret_tuple = []
        for n in nodes:
            rest = nodes[i:]
            for r in rest:
                ret_tuple.append(tuple([n,r]))
            i += 1

        return tuple(ret_tuple)

nodes = set()
edges = set()

for line in s.split():
    clusters = line.split(':')[1].split(';')
    for cluster in clusters:
        _nodes = cluster.split(',')
        nodes.update(_nodes)
        edges.update(combinations(_nodes))

print nodes
print edges
```